# Is there a filter method in Java similar to grep()?

Tags: java, functional-programming, arraylist

I'm writing a small application which needs to perform a common task on a lot of different lists: Filtering objects by given criteria.

For example there's an ArrayList of the class `Foo` which has the attributes `int bar` and `boolean baz`:

```java
class Foo {
    int bar;
    boolean baz;
}
```

I want to retrieve a new list which contains only objects that match a given criteria (for example `bar > 1`) from that ArrayList. In other languages like Perl I'd simply use `grep()` to get all these Objects:

```perl
@where_bar_greater_one = grep { $_->{bar} > 1 } @list;
```

But it doesn't seem to be that easy with Java. Right now I've emulated this behaviour with a static method that iterates over all elements with an anonymous inner class:

```java
interface ListPredicate<T> {
    boolean match(T item);
}
```

```java
class ListUtil {
    public static <T> List<T> grep(List<T> source, ListPredicate<T> predicate) {
        ArrayList<T> results = new ArrayList<T>();
        for(T item : source) {
            if(predicate.match(item)) results.add(item);
        }
        return results;
    }
}
```

```java
ArrayList<Foo> found = new ArrayList<Foo>(ListUtil.grep(list, new ListPredicate<Foo>() {
    @Override public boolean match(Foo item) {
        return item.bar > 1 ? true : false;
    }
}));
```

Compared to the small piece of Perl this code looks rather bloated and I'm wondering if I didn't miss something. So this leaves me with two questions:

1. Is there a shorter (and perhaps cleaner) way to do this without using any external libraries?
2. Are there recommended open-source libraries which provide methods for such common higher-order functions (like `grep`, `foldLeft`, `reduceLeft`, `map` and so on...)?

Comment: Look at Apache CollectionUtils http://commons.apache.org/collections/

Comment: Not that it helps much, but Java 8 is going to have lots of these goodies as part of its lambdas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [JFilter](http://code.google.com/p/jfilter/)  to query java collections.

Another option is to use [Commons Collections](http://commons.apache.org/collections/) with predicates (as explained [here](https://discursive.atlassian.net/wiki/display/CJCOOK/Filtering+a+Collection+with+a+Predicate))

Good luck!

Comment: The problem with Commons Collections is that they don't support generics, which is quite important for collections.

Answer (score 0):

or you can use [grep4j](https://code.google.com/p/grep4j) for java greps. (also works with remote files)